# Mistake in list grammar example in Bjarne's programming book?

Tags: grammar

At this moment I am reading paragraph 6.4.2 of Bjarne Stroustrups book 'Programming Principles and Practice using C++'. In this paragraph he demonstrates the following list grammar:

```
List:
    "{" Sequence "}"
Sequence:
    Element
    Element "," Sequence
Element:
    "A"
    "B"
```

He says that the following are Lists according to the grammar above:

```
{ A }
{ B }
{ A,B }
{A,A,A,A,B }
```

Shouldn't `Element "," Sequence` be `Sequence "," Element` to make `{ A,B }` and `{A,A,A,A,B }` correct Lists according to this grammar?

How I understand this grammar, `A` is a `Sequence`. That makes `B` the `Element`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Element "," Sequence` and `Sequence "," Element` are equivalent here.

Both `A` and `B` are `Element`s:

```
Element:
    "A"
    "B"
```

But every `Element` is also a valid `Sequence`:

```
Sequence:
    Element
```

Basically,

```
Sequence:
  Element "," Sequence
```

means "if you have an element, a comma, and a sequence, that forms another sequence". I.e. this rule lets you add elements at the beginning of a sequence to extend it.

```
Sequence:
  Sequence "," Element
```

means "if you have a sequence, a comma, and an element, that forms another sequence". This rule lets you add elements at the end of a sequence to extend it.

In either case the end result is a list of (comma separated) elements.

Comment: Although left- and right-recursive _definitions_ are equivalent, which you use can affect the parsing process. _Generally_ (as I understand it), a right-recursive grammar is easier to write a parser for than a left-recursive one (see [Why is left recursion bad?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9963/25969) on the CS StackExchange).

Comment: @TripeHound If you're using yacc or bison, prefer left recursion. If you're manually writing a recursive descent parser, you can just skip the recursion part and use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Left and right recursions are equivalent, in the end all ocurrences of `Sequence` must be replaced by `Element` and the order won't matter.

**{ A , B }**:

- List
- { Sequence }
- { Element , Sequence }
- { Element , Element }
- { A , B}

**{ A , A , A , A , B }**:

- List
- { Sequence }
- { Element , Sequence }
- { Element , Element , Sequence }
- { Element , Element , Element , Sequence }
- { Element , Element , Element , Element , Sequence }
- { Element , Element , Element , Element , Element }
- { A , A , A , A , B }

So, both can be generated from the grammar and so are correct lists.

Answer (score 1):

In the *List* `{A,A,A,A,B}`, `A,A,A,A,B` is a *Sequence*.

This is further decomposed to `A`, `A,A,A,B` where `A` is the *Element* (convenient as it is a single *terminal*), and `A,A,A,B` is a *Sequence*. This continues until you reach two single terminals making up the sequence, which are both elements.